# What is the largest memory card that is supported by the Canon IXUS 960 IS?

Tags: memory-card-size, canon-ixus, sdhc

My wife has a Canon IXUS 960 IS, and she's finding that she is filling the 2Gb cards I'd originally got for her too quickly.

I know that some cameras have a maximum supported capacity for memory cards, and rather than waste money on some cards that would turn out to be wasted, I thought I'd try to find the maximum size supported by this camera; So, what is the maximum memory card size supported by the Canon IXUS 960?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Canon's User Guide](http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010516.asp) (and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_Digital_IXUS) and [dpreview](http://www.dpreview.com/news/0708/07082003canonsd950is.asp#specs)) list the camera as compatible with SDHC cards, which has a maximum size of 32GB.

It'd be unusual for something to list as SDHC compatible and not be, and a quick google for memory card problems didn't turn up much of anything.  I'd feel pretty confident using any SDHC card.

Comment: I do remember (back in the SD days) seeing cameras being listed as compatible with SD cards up to N gigabytes. Has this issue gone away with the SDHC standard? Or was that a sneaky way of stating compatibility with only SD, not SDHC?

Comment: @Reid - To my knowledge, yes, the problem should be sorted out (at least until people want more than 32GB cards). SDHC-compatible should mean precisely that.  Not sure about the sneakiness of the situation; might have just been extensions to use higher-capacity cards before there was an SDHC standard.

Comment: Also this is pure speculation, and doesn't really answer the original question: what is the max size card supported. The SDHC spec doesn't have a limit on size, like original SD cards, but just because your camera supports SDHC does not mean it's future proof.

Comment: @Alan http://www.sdcard.org/developers/tech/sdhc/ vs. http://www.sdcard.org/developers/tech/sdxc/ - sizes are part of the spec. I only expressed my confidence that a camera that's labelled as SDHC will actually work with an SDHC card. That's what the specs are for.

Comment: yep you're right. I missed the x vs h. They have 64gb sdxc cards :D

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a strict maximum listed anywhere, but this [spec sheet](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/digital_cameras/powershot_sd_series/powershot_sd960_is#Specifications) from Canon mentioned capacities of 8GB cards. So that would be the minimum maximum. :)

Comment: you've fallen for Canon's gag of using the same numbers for different models internationally. The IXUS 960 is the Powershot SD 950. Not a lot of difference in the specs, though.

Comment: OK, link *not* corrected, as the SD 950 lists the number of photos only up to 512MB. WTF? Anyway, Matt's answer is better.

Comment: I think it's because the 950 comes with a 512mb flash card.